# Blender on Google Colab not finding Graphics Card

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Up until few days ago I was able to run Blender(or sheep it) headless on Google Colab with an GPU(K80 or T4). Now running keras/tensorflow does work fine but blender cant detect the GPU at all and Sheepit tells me that

> "cuInit Failed ret: 100"

nvidia-smi results with:

```
Sat Aug 24 19:48:06 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 430.40       Driver Version: 418.67       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla K80           Off  | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   33C    P8    25W / 149W |      0MiB / 11441MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The following script did work fine for few months and detected the GPU properly and setup blender to use the available GPU.
https://gist.github.com/donmahallem/a05100077ec1327268f28f0b2bd8da60

I tried a lot but my nvidia/unix foo is pretty limited. I tried to find out if the CUDA Version changed and tried to downgrade the cuda version to 9.2 but couldn't get it to work again.

Comment: @rjg yes, I did see that entry. The command runs without erros but still no GPU is listed

Comment: Seems like a configuration and/or driver issue on Google's side. What's also strange is that even the CPU doesn't get listed unless you have the `prefs.addons['cycles'].preferences.get_devices()` line in your script. That shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Or Blender relies on something for device detection that doesn't apply to Google Colab since some update.

Comment: @rjg the CPUs are listed. I just happen to ignore them in that script as GPU+CPU with on Colab is awefully slow from my testing(only dual core cpu). I did some more testing in the meantime. Both blender 2.79 and 2.80 aren't working anymore for some reason. Maybe they updated the vm ( driver or something) BUT everything else even building and running cuda examples are working fine. Trying to build blender on colab wasn't succesful yet.

Comment: I know that you don't enable them in the linked script in your question. What I meant was the CPU isn't in `cprefs.devices` without calling `prefs.addons['cycles'].preferences.get_devices()`. However that is intended behavior because the list isn't auto-updated, not even for the systems CPU, so that call is always required to get the current devices. (https://developer.blender.org/T60618)

Comment: I spent yesterday's night trying to find the issue and haven't come up with a solution or a cause that would point at Blender. I doubt that compiling Blender on Colab would make any difference for the detection of CUDA devices. Just to be sure I've created a notebook for compiling it, let's see how that goes.

Comment: Ah, now I get what you were saying. Didn't know that with get_devices as the script did work without problems for several weeks prior. Maybe they blacklisted blender from seeing/using the gpu but I don't know how they would have gone about this. Thanks for trying to build it yourself too as I got stuck several times 90% the way.

Comment: Right that's what I suspect too. No problem, you're welcome!

Comment: That's why I tried to compile it myself as there might be some kind of application finger printing and googled if there is a way of "masking" hardware from certain apps but this is far beyond my skill level. Apps don't advertise themself to cuda hardware themself afaik but as I said thats stuff is far beyond I am able to read into the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to stem from the `libtcmalloc.so.4` installed with Google Colab. For some reason, which isn't clear to me yet, uninstalling the `libtcmalloc-minimal4` that comes with Google Colab by default and installing the `libtcmalloc-minimal4` package from the Ubuntu repository lets Blender detect the GPU and work properly without using sudo (no more segfault in `tcmalloc.cc` occur).

In order to fix the `LD_PRELOAD`, it has to be set to the correct shared object library after installing the working package.

I can only speculate as to what the problem actually is. `LD_PRELOAD` allows to replace the allocator the program uses with a custom one, in this case TCmalloc. Perhaps there is a bug in the specific version that Google uses.

I've put the Blender archive, project file and python script on Google Drive for faster loading in the notebook below.

---

**blender_v3.ipynb**

```
import os

os.environ["LD_PRELOAD"] = ""

!apt remove libtcmalloc-minimal4
!apt install libtcmalloc-minimal4

os.environ["LD_PRELOAD"] = "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4.3.0"

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

!cp -n "./drive/My Drive/blender-2.80-linux-glibc217-x86_64.tar.bz2" .
!cp "./drive/My Drive/enable_gpu_v3.py" .
!cp "./drive/My Drive/test.blend" .
!tar -xjf ./blender-2.80-linux-glibc217-x86_64.tar.bz2
!./blender-2.80-linux-glibc217-x86_64/blender -b test.blend -P enable_gpu_v3.py -noaudio -E CYCLES -o "./drive/My Drive/gpu_test_" -f 1
```

---

**enable_gpu_v3.py**

```
import bpy

prefs = bpy.context.preferences
cuda_devices, opencl_devices = bpy.context.preferences.addons['cycles'].preferences.get_devices()

scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
scene.cycles.device = 'GPU'
cprefs = prefs.addons['cycles'].preferences

try:
    cprefs.compute_device_type = "CUDA"
except TypeError:
    print("Could not enable CUDA")

for device in cuda_devices:
    print(f'Activating {device.name}')
    device.use = True
```

Comment: Note that removing `libtcmalloc-minimal4` also removes `google-perftools` in case you need them.

Comment: Thanks! They must have changed something else too. Before you couldn't run blender without sudo. Now with sudo it won't find the gpu but without it does. Really weird.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also facing the same problem. I think colab is not allowing GPU to use for any commands that include "sudo" in it.

Solution I found was to install blender and then run the command to render without "sudo".

I installed blender from PPA ppa:thomas-schiex/blender

commands to execute:

```
!sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thomas-schiex/blender
!sudo apt-get install blender
!blender -b -P script.py filename.blend -o fileoutput -F PNG -f 1
```

script.py contains code to select gpu, I generally upload to colab. Save following code as script.py

```
import bpy, _cycles

bpy.context.scene.cycles.device = 'GPU'

avail_devices = _cycles.available_devices('CUDA')
print(avail_devices)

prop = bpy.context.preferences.addons['cycles'].preferences

prop.get_devices(prop.compute_device_type)
prop.compute_device_type = 'CUDA'

for device in prop.devices:
    if device.type == 'CUDA':
        print('device: ', device)
        device.use = True
```

this worked for me !

Comment: Interesting, this works. The question is why both the official build and the Ubuntu package don't detect the GPU and get the tcmalloc error without sudo.

Comment: Thanks! This does work too. Interestingly before you had to use sudo otherwise blender would just silently force quit for some reason.