# How do I get blender to render using GPU on google colab?

Tags: gpu

I've been trying to use Google Colab to render animations but I can't get it to render using the graphics card. I change the hardware accelerator to GPU, but it doesn't use the GPU to render it only uses the RAM, I think this is the case because it doesn't use any of the GPU RAM, and when I change the hardware accelerator to None it still works the same. In the .blend file the render settings are Cycles, GPU Compute.

This is the line I use to render, maybe something's wrong with it.

```
!./blender-3.1.2-linux-x64/blender -b $filename -s 1 -e 100 -t 960 -a --cycles-device CUDA
```

Comment: Does this post answer your question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149655/blender-on-google-colab-not-finding-graphics-card
(Note: I haven't tested this in a while, so you may be experiencing a different issue or the solution might not work anymore)